# How can i expand children of fab in a row format?

Tags: flutter, dart, floating-action-button

[image]

Need to add like this. children should be parallel to fab.

Need to add speeddialchild children of FAB in a row instead of column.

[image]

In the above picture added speeddialchild in a column. How can i add speeddialchild in a row ?

Comment: have you try put `direction` on Speed Dial? I never use it before, but in its example code, there are `direction: speedDialDirection` property.

Comment: Yes. But direction property will align the children on top or bottom or sides. But i need to add row on top of FAB both should be in  parallel

Comment: Is `direction : left`  is not your desired result? maybe you can give a picture so we can have clear image about what you want to achieve here.

Comment: I know its not the answer, but maybe you can check this packages? https://pub.dev/packages/navigation_action_bar. It has exact design with what you want.

Comment: @AnandaPramono  Thank you. But the was not a null safe package.